# flask-bootstrap quick_form missing Submit button

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, flask-bootstrap

Trying to use flask-bootstrap quick_form.

HTML template my-form.j2:

```
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
{% extends "layout.j2" %}

{% block content %}

<h1>My form</h1>
{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}

{% endblock content %}
```

Form class:

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    """A WTForm for configuring vehicle information"""
    field1 = StringField('First field', [wtforms.validators.required()])
    field2 = StringField('Second field', [wtforms.validators.required()])
    field3 = StringField('Third field', [wtforms.validators.required()])
```

Form handler:

```
@app.route('/myform', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def my_form():
    form = MyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        myData = form.data
        return redirect("/")
    return render_template("my-form.j2", form=form)
```

Unfortunately I am not seeing a Submit button rendered, even if I add
`{{ form.submit }}` to my table.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can add the input field directly after `{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}` and put both of these inside an HTML form:

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login">
```

**Example**

```
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
{% extends "layout.j2" %}

{% block content %}

<h1>My form</h1>
<form method="POST" action="/">
    {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 13):

The answer of @atwalsh work just fine, but you can also put your submit button in your class, and then call it in your template:

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    field1 = StringField('First field', [wtforms.validators.required()])
    field2 = StringField('Second field', [wtforms.validators.required()])
    field3 = StringField('Third field', [wtforms.validators.required()])
--> submit_button = SubmitField('Submit Form')
```

And then put in your template:

```
{{ wtf.quick_form(form, button_map={'submit_button': 'primary'}) }}
                            ^            ^
```

Edit:
You also need to import the SubmitField method:

```
from wtforms import SubmitField
```

Comment: This is a more polished approach.